# Using a Javascript Promise in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise

I'm a total n00b to Promises, and would like to use them more, but need a little help. Take the code example below:

```
for (var key in list){
    DoSomething(list[key])
        .then(function(){
            console.log(key);
        });
}

function DoSomething(item){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve();
    });
}
```

The `console.log(key)` part wont work correctly because the variable `key` is modified in the outer scope. A way to fix that might be to `resolve` the promise with the `key` value but unfortunately, the DoSomething method is part of a shared library.

```
for (var key in list){
    DoSomething(list[key], key)
        .then(function(key){
            console.log(key);
        });
}

function DoSomething(item, key){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(key);
    });
}
```

Is there any other way to get the for loop `console.log(key)` to work correctly?

Comment: using "let" should do the work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use let instead of var and it would work

```js
let list = {a:1, b:2};

for (let key in list){
    DoSomething(list[key])
        .then(function(){
            console.log(key);
        });
}

function DoSomething(item){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve();
    });
}
```

Comment: Please close-vote obvious duplicates instead of answering them.

Comment: @Cerbrus Are you sure you specified correct duplicate?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: Maybe not the best one, but it does answer the question.

Comment: @Cerbrus I fail to see how though

Comment: @Cerbrus The "Closure inside loop - simple practical example' Q might be better

Answer (score 1):

Use IIFE

```
for (var key in list){
    (function(key){
        DoSomething(list[key])
        .then(function(){
            console.log(key);
        });
     })(key);
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter - Reason please

Comment: Since the OP's using Promises already, ___let___'s suggest some more modern methods than an IIFE. also, please close-vote obvious duplicates instead of answering them.

Comment: @Cerbrus - For that I wish there was es6 tag.

Comment: promises are ES6.

Comment: ES6 aside, this is a pretty cool way to solve the problem that I didnt know before. Thanks. +1

Comment: @Cerbrus - Thanks! Noticed now! You have got the point proved, however, I would still argue on the answer, It is not incorrect and the best part being OP acknowledges it!